# SQL threads from many sub domains or sub folders on website

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, paypal

I have a script that I wrote for Online games payments, now the thing is the people who's going to use it , will use it on my host on a sub folder ( payments.example.com/name/ )

I haven't figure out how to build an instance API in order to make whole script work from one directory ( using $_GET ) for system to recognize who they want to pay to seems a little wrong, or maybe i'm just over stressed I don't know, you can suggest me a solution if you can.

Now my question is , since the host will have, for example, 20 different project using the same script copy ( just with different sql settings ) and all of them will send an info to their databases, Plus all that copies will send info to main database in my host already ( for logs and statistics in their admin panel )

Will that cause any problems? Is there anything you can suggest for better performance and usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your livesystem and database Server Quality. If its a good one it shouldn't have problems with doing that. I think you just need to start your Service and Monitor the Server Memory and CPU Usage.

If you already want to see wether or not you have some narrow pieces in your code, your probably want to use a PHP Profiler to profile your Code on your production server.

See http://www.xdebug.org/ as example tool. But you need to deactivate it bevor Publishing the Service on your live System

And you should think about the Copys in youre main Database. Thats just additional non nessesary traffic between PHP and you Database.

Hope I helped you